Specify a namespace in the module's build file when debugging my flutter code
hi i am trying to debug my flutter code in vs code but get this errore its really a nightmare for me and dont really understand what what this means

Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

 If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.

i dont use android studio
heres my flutter code
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';

class DataReadAndWritePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DataReadAndWritePageState createState() => _DataReadAndWritePageState();
}

class _DataReadAndWritePageState extends State<DataReadAndWritePage> {
  FlutterBlue flutterBlue = FlutterBlue.instance;
  List<ScanResult> _scanResults = [];
  late BluetoothDevice _selectedDevice;
  late BluetoothCharacteristic _characteristic;
  String _dataValue = '';
  final TextEditingController _dataController = TextEditingController();
  late StreamSubscription<List<int>> _dataStreamSubscription;

  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  final SERVICE_UUID = "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b";
  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  final CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8";

  void _startScan() async {
    setState(() {
      _scanResults = [];
    });

    Stream<ScanResult> scanResults =
        flutterBlue.scan(timeout: const Duration(seconds: 10));
    scanResults.listen((scanResult) {
      setState(() {
        _scanResults.add(scanResult);
      });
    });
  }

  void _connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) async {
    setState(() {
      _selectedDevice = device;
    });

    await device.connect();

    List<BluetoothService> services = await device.discoverServices();
    BluetoothService service =
        services.firstWhere((s) => s.uuid.toString() == SERVICE_UUID);
    _characteristic = service.characteristics
        .firstWhere((c) => c.uuid.toString() == CHARACTERISTIC_UUID);

    _dataStreamSubscription = _characteristic.value.listen((value) {
      setState(() {
        _dataValue = value.map((byte) => byte.toString()).join(', ');
      });
    });
  }

  void _writeData() async {
    int value = int.parse(_dataController.text);
    await _characteristic.write(List.from([value]));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _dataStreamSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Data Read and Write'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _startScan,
            child: const Text('Start Scan'),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _scanResults.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                ScanResult scanResult = _scanResults[index];
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(scanResult.device.name),
                  subtitle: Text(scanResult.device.id.toString()),
                  onTap: () => _connectToDevice(scanResult.device),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          if (_selectedDevice != null)
            Column(
              children: [
                Text('Data Value: $_dataValue'),
                TextField(
                  controller: _dataController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Data Value'),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: _writeData,
                  child: const Text('Write Data'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

